# Clarify two columns of the same name

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT CableNumber, CblType, ApprxmtLngth, ME.EquipmentNumber, ME2.EquipmentNumber, CblStatus, InstallMthd, S.PrdtCd FROM CableId C
 INNER JOIN MajorEquipment ME ON C.FromLoc = ME.MEId
 INNER JOIN MajorEquipment ME2 ON C.ToLoc = ME2.MEId
 INNER JOIN SupplierInfo S ON C.SupplierId = S.SupplierId WHERE
 (@CblType IS NULL OR CblType LIKE @CblType)
 AND (@CblStatus IS NULL OR CblStatus LIKE @CblStatus)
 AND (@FromLoc IS NULL OR ME.EquipmentNumber LIKE @FromLoc)
 AND (@ToLoc IS NULL OR ME2.EquipmentNumber LIKE @ToLoc);
```

When I pass the result into a model, how do I define which `EquipmentNumber` goes into which variable?

```
while (mySqlReader.Read())
{
    CableID_Controller.CList.Add(new CableID_Model
    {
        CableNumber = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CableNumber"]),
        CableType = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblType"]),
        SupplierPart = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["PrdtCd"]),
        CableLength = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlReader["ApprxmtLngth"]),
        InstallMethod = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["InstallMthd"]),
        Origin = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["ME.EquipmentNumber"]),
        Destination = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["ME2.EquipmentNumber"]),
        Status = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblStatus"])
     });
}
```

Because `ME.EquipmentNumber` and `ME2.EquipmentNumber` are not the actual names of the headers.

Comment: I would give it a try. I don't know for sure, but I think the driver will leave the names out. But why not just alias them?

Comment: Doing it this way gives the error: `Could not find the specified column in the results: ME.EquipmentNumber`

Comment: So what is wrong with aliases?

Comment: Never heard of them until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

Just give the columns different alias (`EquipmentNumber1` and `EquipmentNumber2`) in your query and code with the `as` operator. You have to remove the `ME1` and `ME2` in your code too.

#### Sample

```
SELECT CableNumber, CblType, ApprxmtLngth, ME.EquipmentNumber as EquipmentNumber1, ME2.EquipmentNumber as EquipmentNumber2, CblStatus, InstallMthd, S.PrdtCd FROM CableId C
 INNER JOIN MajorEquipment ME ON C.FromLoc = ME.MEId
 INNER JOIN MajorEquipment ME2 ON C.ToLoc = ME2.MEId
 INNER JOIN SupplierInfo S ON C.SupplierId = S.SupplierId WHERE
 (@CblType IS NULL OR CblType LIKE @CblType)
 AND (@CblStatus IS NULL OR CblStatus LIKE @CblStatus)
 AND (@FromLoc IS NULL OR ME.EquipmentNumber LIKE @FromLoc)
 AND (@ToLoc IS NULL OR ME2.EquipmentNumber LIKE @ToLoc);

while (mySqlReader.Read())
{
    CableID_Controller.CList.Add(new CableID_Model
    {
        CableNumber = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CableNumber"]),
        CableType = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblType"]),
        SupplierPart = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["PrdtCd"]),
        CableLength = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlReader["ApprxmtLngth"]),
        InstallMethod = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["InstallMthd"]),
        Origin = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["EquipmentNumber1"]),
        Destination = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["EquipmentNumber2"]),
        Status = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblStatus"])
     });
}
```

#### More Information

- [How to MySQL - ALIAS](http://www.howtomysql.net/alias.html)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query by adding aliases to the returned columns:

```
SELECT CableNumber,
       CblType,
       ApprxmtLngth,
       ME.EquipmentNumber AS EquipmentNumber1,
       ME2.EquipmentNumber AS EquipmentNumber2,
       CblStatus,
       InstallMthd, [...]
```

You can then refer to `EquipmentNumber1` and `EquipmentNumber2` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not give the columns different [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)?

> SQL aliases are used to temporarily rename a table or a column
>   heading.

Something like

```
SELECT 
 CableNumber, 
 CblType, 
 ApprxmtLngth, 
 ME.EquipmentNumber as MEEquipmentNumber, 
 ME2.EquipmentNumber as ME2EquipmentNumber,  
 CblStatus, 
 InstallMthd, 
 S.PrdtCd 
...
```

You would then use these aliases in your C# code. Something like

```
while (mySqlReader.Read())
{
    CableID_Controller.CList.Add(new CableID_Model
    {
        CableNumber = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CableNumber"]),
        CableType = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblType"]),
        SupplierPart = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["PrdtCd"]),
        CableLength = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlReader["ApprxmtLngth"]),
        InstallMethod = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["InstallMthd"]),
        Origin = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["MEEquipmentNumber"]),
        Destination = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["ME2EquipmentNumber"]),
        Status = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["CblStatus"])
     });
}
```